# gscam can no longer be run

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used `gscam` for a while and I'm quite happy with it. However, since a week it will no longer start. I get the known 'PAUSED' error, but I don't think any settings have changed. This is the output of running it:

```
$ rosrun gscam gscam
[ INFO] [1375955831.001182268]: Using gstreamer config from env: "v4l2src 
device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=25/1, width=640,height=360 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
[ INFO] [1375955831.004123416]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1375955831.004218662]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/raf/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml
[ERROR] [1375955831.004328229]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/raf/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml]
[ WARN] [1375955831.004371869]: Camera calibration file /home/raf/.ros/camera_info/camera.yaml not found.
[ INFO] [1375955831.004409639]: Loaded camera calibration from 
[FATAL] [1375955831.121288814]: Failed to PAUSE stream, check your gstreamer configuration.
[FATAL] [1375955831.121384226]: Failed to initialize gscam stream!
```

The settings of the webcam at `dev/video0` are:

```
$ ls -l /dev/video0
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 raf video 81, 0 aug  7 08:24 /dev/video0
```

Note that I have read and write permissions set for every user and am myself owner of the device.

I also tried to remove and reinstall gscam, to no avail. Does anyone know what else I can try?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71845/gscam-can-no-longer-be-run/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-08-08**:
Maybe try with gst-launch to see that you get an image (end with e.g. ximagesink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the comment of @TommyP, I did:

```
$ gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=25/1, width=640,height=360 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ximagesink
```

Which is what `gscam` also tries more or less to do. This gave following output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Could not negotiate format
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2830): gst_base_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
Check your filtered caps, if any
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The part where it says "could not negotiate format' indicated that my parameters were faulty, e.i. my camera does not support them.

Using GTK UVC video viewer, I found that the only framerates supported by my webcam are 30/1 and 15/1. `gscam` works using either one of these.

---

Originally posted by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) with karma: 386 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1